# Can I use tf-idf on OneHotEcoded data?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, deep-learning

I have a dataset of 800 rows and 16k columns.
It's in a OneHotEcoding format (binary: 0,1). Such that if a column value exists in a row, then row[col] = 1, else, = 0.
These are 16k features in my dataset. How can I use tfidf to select 5k & 10k features from this?

eg of my data:

```
ID col1 col2 col3 col4
a   0    0    1    0
b   1    0    0    0 
c   0    1    1    1 
d   0    0    0    1
```

but this, for ~800 rows and 16k columns.
I tried topic modelling and selected the top 300 features from the dataset (using LDA) but that wasnt enough.
I've been asked to use tf-idf and select 5k features from the dataframe. (Originally I was asked to **try  features around 5k to 16k with 500 to 1k steps in-between**
).
I didn't understand what's been originally asked but want to figure out using tf-idf to select the features. Then maybe could run the same for 6k,7k,8k...16k features?
Any help with what library to use and how to code it would be helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use an OneHotEcoding format to compute tf-idf scores.

Here is the formula of tf-idf:

```
tf-idf = tf*idf
```

`tf`: No. of times a word appears in a document/Total No. of words in the document.
`idf`: log(No. of documents/No. of documents that contain the word)

As you can see, the OneHotEcoding format allows you to calculate `idf` but cannot calculate `tf`. To calculate `tf`, you need to know how many times a word appears in a document. However, the OneHotEcoding format only counts a word one time in a document no matter how many times it appears. For example, if "apple" shows in a document three times, OneHotEcoding only counts it as 1.

If you have original text data (before converting it to a bag of words), you can use [TfidfVectorizer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html) in sklearn to compute tf-idf scores.